# Likert scale analysis

Tags: statistics

I have collected survey using a 5 point Likert scale (ranging from very negative affect to very positive affect). I am writing a scientific paper so wish to follow similar procedures.

Is it appropriate to provide statistical analysis to compare the 'mean' (I know that the idea of a mean in Likert data is contentious in itself) response to 'no impact'? For instance, if 75% of respondents have answered 'somewhat positive affect' and 25% have answered 'very positive affect', is it a requirement/desireable to use a statistical test (such as the one sample sign test) to compare this test this against a null hypothesis of the 'mean' response being 'no impact'?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: The 'mean' of a Likert scale is contentious for good reason. Over the last couple of decades, the field of psychology seems to have accumulated a vast literature of results that cannot be replicated. Misuse of the Likert scale and misunderstanding of the meaning of the P-value are are major contenders as the root causes of this disaster. Whatever you do, please treat your Likert data as ordinal categorical (for which medians exist and means do not), and not as numerical data. // Depending on n, a median-based sign test may not have suff power. Perhaps a Wilcoxon test or a permutation test.

Comment: If you have a large sample with 100% of subjects expressing a positive point of view, then it's pretty clear that subjects take a generally positive view. If thats 3 out of $n=4$ 'somewhat pos' and one 'very pos', then it's hard to draw any conclusions. How about posting actual counts in each category and leaving a Comment. Then maybe I (or someone else) can give a more informed opinion how to go ahead.

Comment: Hi BruceET, thanks very much for your advice. As an example, take: very positive impact: 18%, somewhat positive impact: 53%, no impact: 18%, somewhat negative impact: 12%, very negative impact: 0%. I have so far used a sign test on this -this appears to me the only test for which this data fulfills the assumptions - with a result of p = 0.035. Also, am I right to report the hypotheses as H0: median = 'no impact'. H1: median =/= 'no impact. ?

Comment: Thanks for that info. Prior obligations most of today, but plan to take a serious look at your numbers soon. Interesting problem.

Comment: **Please give sample size.** Can't do anything without knowing that. (Especially for categorical data, percentages mean nothing without knowing $n.$ [A major flaw of many graphs for categorical data (bar charts, pie charts, etc.) is lack of info about sample size.]

Comment: Thanks - n = 50 in this case but I am also analysing instances where n = 15.

Answer (score 0):

For a talk and perhaps for a figure in a forthcoming paper, I would suggest
you show a pie chart: Color 'Strongly Pos' deep cyan, 'Pos' light cyan, 'No' grey,
"Neg' peach, 'Strongly neg' deep orange. Then note that cyan areas (some kind
of positive) take up far more than half of the pie (71% of respondents). Also, 
because there are $n = 50$ respondents a 95% Agresti-style ("plue-four") 
confidence interval for "overall positive" is $(.56,.81),$ so we're pretty
sure the exact population proportion of "overall positive" exceeds half.
[There are some approximations computing the CI, because 53% of 50 isn't an integer.]

I do not see how you get P-value 0.035. First, intuitively that seems a 'weak'
P-value (rejecting at the 5% level, but not at the 3% level), while the
data seem **extremely** strongly positive. More than half of the results are 'Strong
positive' or 'Positive' responses, so the observed median response is 'Positive'.

If I have understood your data correctly, here are results of Minitab's 
output for a sign test (coding categories as 2=Strongly pos, 1=Positive, 0=None, -1=Negative).

```
Sign Test for Median: C1 

Sign test of median =  0.00000 versus ≠ 0.00000

     N  Below  Equal  Above       P  Median
x   50      6      9     35  0.0000   1.000
```

The tiny P-value indicates that if the true opinion were 'None', then
it would be almost impossible to get as many 'Strong pos' and 'Positive'
responses out of 50 as you observed.

I think a permutation test would be more powerful than a sign test
for data of the general kind you have, especially with smaller $n$'s But for the data you give in your
Comment, there is no point doing a permutation test because the sign
test gives such a tiny P-value.

Please take another look at your data counts, and let me know what you find.
Maybe you have given wrong counts, or maybe I have misunderstood what you said.

Comment: Some typos corrected for clarity several hours after original post. Essence unchanged.